# is postgres BEFORE UPDATE trigger atomic?

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I trying to do conditional UPDATE trigger. It should update row only if certain condition, depending on old row data, is met (I know I can simply do UPDATE ... WHERE ... but from various reasons trigger is the way to go for us):

```
CREATE
OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_only_with_higher_timestamp()
  RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
 IF
NEW.timestamp < OLD.timestamp THEN
    RETURN OLD;
END IF;

RETURN NEW;
END;$$;


CREATE TRIGGER avoid_updating_rows_with_lower_timestamp
    BEFORE UPDATE
    ON table
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_only_with_higher_timestamp();
```

My question is, is this operation atomic? Or could it happen that I base that condition on old data which might not be the most up to date at the time?

Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Why do you need a trigger in the first place? Use GREATEST() in your UPDATE statement to make sure the timestamp always uses the newest one.

Comment: I cannot, UPDATE statement is not under my control

Comment: You are not really concerned with atomicity but the `I` in `ACID` isolation. For that I point you at [MVCC](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc.html)((Multiversion Concurrency Control). The short answer is it depends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That trigger is safe. PostgreSQL takes the row lock *before* it executes the `BEFORE` trigger, so the row is already locked against concurrent data modifications.

You can optimize the trigger function considerably if you `RETURN NULL` rather than `RETURN OLD` if you don't want the `UPDATE` to happen. Returning NULL will abort the operation (without an error), while returning `OLD` will perform an `UPDATE` that has no effect, but costs performance.

Comment: Please, can you elaborate: does `postgres` release the lock before the `AFTER` triggers execute or only after they've finished? I have a similar question at hand [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75934840/are-after-update-triggers-for-each-row-atomic).

Comment: @winwin All locks are always held until the end of the transaction.