# Are `AFTER UPDATE` triggers `FOR EACH ROW` atomic?

Tags: sql, postgresql, atomic, acid, plpython

I'd like to insert a row inside a "history" table whenever the original row gets modified (updated). I'd like to use original row's ID as a `FOREIGN KEY` for the `history` table. But this ID *might* change.

Have a look at the example below:

```
CREATE TABLE account
(
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    username TEXT NOT NULL,
    balance BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);

CREATE TABLE account_balance_change
(
    account_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    diff BIGINT NOT NULL,
    ts TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (account_id) REFERENCES account (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE FUNCTION dump_diff()
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE plpython3u
AS
$$
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()

old = TD['old']
new = TD['new']

diff = new['balance'] - old['balance']

query = f"""
INSERT INTO
    account_balance_change
    (
        account_id,
        diff,
        ts
    )
VALUES
    ($1, $2, $3)
;
"""
# i know it should be cached, but for the sake of simplicity...
stmt = plpy.prepare(query, ["BIGINT", "BIGINT", "TIMESTAMPTZ"])
# see how it's using new['id'], so that there can be no mistake in the new record
stmt.execute([new['id'], diff, now])
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER after_account_balance_update_trigger
AFTER UPDATE OF balance ON account
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION
    store_diff()
;
```

The expected behavior is that every time someone `UPDATE`s any `account`'s `balance` value, the balance difference and date and time of such change would be written into the `account_balance_change` table.

But as per system requirements, the ID *might* change or get deleted.

Therefore, are we safe to assume that `new['id']` won't change at the time of this trigger being executed? Can we actually end up in a spot where a race condition occurred and `new['id']` no longer exists in the database?

It all basically boils down to one question: **Are `AFTER UPDATE` `TRIGGER`s atomic with respect to the `UPDATE` operation they belong to**?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21464646/1080354